# How do I create an optional list of choices in a discord slash command?

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

I am creating a game using a discord bot and am in the process of switching to slash commands. I am trying to create a command to inspect an item (as in an in-game item e.g. "iron ore") and I want the player to be able to choose from a list of all items in the game while using the inspect command. I'd imagine it would look like this: /inspect iron_ore, where the iron_ore is an item select from a list. I have successfully implemented selecting from a list of members in a command, but I do not know how to get a selectable list from other sources.

In the snippet below, I have a database query that gets all of the items in the game and returns them in a list. Additionally, how can I make this optional? I would like the /inspect command to work even if the player doesn't input an item.

```
db_query = get_all_items_in_db()

@tree.command(name = "inspect", description = "Examine an item in more detail")
@app_commands.describe(item = "Select an item to inspect")
async def self(interaction: discord.Interaction, item: str):
await interaction.response.send_message(f"You inspect {item}!")
```

I've tried passing the database query into @app_commands.choices, but it does not accept lists as a datatype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make an argument optional, you can type annotate it as - very unsurprisingly - `Optional`. Alternatively, giving it a default value will work as well.

To dynamically populate the suggestions shown to a user (I think this is what you want) you can use an `autocomplete`. There's an example in the docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=autocomplete#discord.app_commands.autocomplete

Note that when using an autocomplete the user can only select one item, and they aren't forced to choose anything. These are only *suggestions*, and they can type in whatever they want.

If you don't want that, then there's also an official example for how to create select menus ("dropdowns"): https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/views/dropdown.py